# C# Nested initialization strangeness

Tags: c#, syntax, semantics, c#-6.0

Under the premise that these initialization statements compile

```
List<int> l = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
Dictionary<int, int> d = new Dictionary<int, int> { [1] = 11, [2] = 22 };
Foo f = new Foo { Bar = new List<int>() };
```

and this will not

```
List<int> l = { 1, 2, 3 };
Dictionary<int, int> d = { [1] = 11, [2] = 22 };
Foo f = { Bar = new List<int>() };
```

I have a question about nested initializations. Given the following class

```
public class Foo {
    public List<int> Bar { get; set; } = new List<int>();
    public Dictionary<int, Foo> Baz { get; set; } = new Dictionary<int, Foo>();
}
```

I discovered by accident that you could actually do this:

```
Foo f = new Foo {
    Bar = { 1, 2, 3 },
    Baz = {
        [1] = {
            Bar = { 4, 5, 6 }
        }
    }
};
```

While it does compile it throws a `KeyNotFoundException`. So I changed the properties to

```
public List<int> Bar { get; set; } = new List<int> { 4, 5, 6 };
public Dictionary<int, Foo> Baz { get; set; }
    = new Dictionary<int, Foo> { [1] = new Foo { Bar = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 } } };
```

assuming that this is some unusual notation for replacing existing members. Now the initialization throws a `StackOverflowException`.

So my question is, why does the expression even compile? What is it supposed to do? I feel like I must be missing something really obvious.

Comment: The stack overflow is simply due to the fact that creating a `Foo` will create a `Dictionary`  and creates a `Foo` to add to it, that in turn creates a `Dictionary` with a `Foo` and so on.

Comment: Note you can change it to `Baz = { {1, new Foo { Bar = {4,5,6}}}};` to get it to  work because that notation uses the `Add(Tkey, TValue)` of `Dictionary` and in that case it will not compile without the `new Foo`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So my question is, why does the expression even compile?

It's an object initializer with a collection initializer value. From the C# specification section 7.6.10.2:

> A member initializer that specifies a collection initializer after the equals sign is an initialization of an embedded collection. Instead of assigning a new collection to the field or property, the elements given in the initializer are added to the collection referenced by the field or property.

So your code code is roughly equivalent to:

```
Foo tmp = new Foo();
tmp.Bar.Add(1);
tmp.Bar.Add(2);
tmp.Bar.Add(3);
tmp.Baz[1].Bar.Add(4); // This will throw KeyNotFoundException if Baz is empty
tmp.Baz[1].Bar.Add(5);
tmp.Baz[1].Bar.Add(6);
Foo f = tmp;
```

Your initialization version will throw a `StackOverflowException` because the initializer for `Foo` needs to create a new instance of `Foo`, which needs to create a new instance of `Foo` etc.

Comment: The StackOverflowException was a stupid oversight. I wasn't aware of this part of the specification though. Thanks

Comment: I still don't get this. In which line of code is an object instance of "Foo" gets created recursively?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `temp.Baz[1].Bar.Add(4)`?

Comment: @Sung If you mean the `Foo` in the dictionary, then there isn't a `Foo` being created, it's assuming there is a `Foo` already at index 1 and it's just adding values to it's `Bar`.

Comment: I wonder what use case they had in mind with the "typeless" Dictionary initialization. This notation would be really nice and concise if it did `(tmp.Baz.ContainsKey(1) ? tmp.Baz[1] :  tmp.Baz[1] = new ...).Bar.Add(4)` instead

Comment: @MarcusS.: Not sure what you mean by "typeless" - it's just using an indexer in the same way that it would use a property.

Comment: Inartfully expressed. Basicly, from looking at the code, I would expect the collection initializer to create a new object, esp. because it is probably more usual to define a dictionary inside an object initialization than modifying an existing instance.

Supporting something in the form of `f.Baz = { [2] = ..., [3] = ... }` might be more useful

Comment: @MarcusS.: Collection initializers never create collections - they only ever populate them. I find it helpful to be able to tell the difference easily. To create the dictoinary, you just need `f.Baz = new Dictionary<int, Foo> { [2] = ... }`. Again, then it's clear what it's doing.

Comment: Sadly, nested object initializers don't seem to be documented [on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).  They're in the C# spec (7.6.10.2 of [the C# 5.0 Spec](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029)): "A member initializer that specifies an object initializer after the equals sign is a *nested object initializer*, i.e. an initialization of an embedded object. [...] Assignments in the nested object initializer are treated as assignments to members of the field or property."